# FixedUpdate not adding a force to player's Rigidbody

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a movement script for my 2D platformer, and this code stopped working as soon as I moved the AddForce command to FixedUpdate rather than Update. It will still print the Debug.Log, and it will print the correct value of the Movment  Variable, but the Rigidbody does not move at all when I use the arrow keys in-game.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playerMovment : MonoBehaviour
{
    float hInput;
    float moveSpeed = 3;
    float accel = 1f;
    float decel;
    float Movment;
    [SerializeField] Rigidbody2D rb;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        decel = accel * -1f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        calcMovment(); 
    }

    void calcMovment()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            hInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * moveSpeed * 1.5f;
        }
        else
        {
            hInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * moveSpeed;
        }

        float targetSpeed = hInput * moveSpeed;
        //Debug.Log(targetSpeed);
        float speedDiff = targetSpeed - rb.velocity.x;
        //Debug.Log(speedDiff);
        float accelRate = (Mathf.Abs(targetSpeed) > 0.01f) ? accel : decel;
        //Debug.Log(accelRate);
        Movment = Mathf.Pow(Mathf.Abs(speedDiff) * accelRate, 0.5f) * Mathf.Sign(speedDiff);
        //Debug.Log(Movment);
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Debug.Log(Movment);
        rb.AddForce(Movment * Vector2.right);
        //Debug.Log(rb.velocity.x);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the the value of ```Movment```?

Answer (score 0):

The problem begins in these 2 lines of code:

```
float accelRate = (Mathf.Abs(targetSpeed) > 0.01f) ? accel : decel;
Movment = Mathf.Pow(Mathf.Abs(speedDiff) * accelRate, 0.5f) * Mathf.Sign(speedDiff);
```

`accelRate` becomes negative in one moment which leads to the negative base in in the `Mathf.Pow()` the second line, and according to the official MSDN documentation ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.pow?view=net-7.0)), if `x < 0 but not NegativeInfinity; y is not an integer, NegativeInfinity, or PositiveInfinity -> NaN`, and in your case `x` is `Mathf.Abs(speedDiff) * accelRate` and it's negative